# How to structure classes, apply business rules when couple value objects depend on each other?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Basically I have two value objects each representing price. Rule goes one price cannot be greater than other. There might be case when only one of them are specified.

How to enforce this rule and where? Keep two separate objects and when one gets constructed pass other to it? Sounds a bit weird because inverse rule must be applied to other. I do not want to keep both values in one object because I do not need them to be coupled when I use those values.

Comment: Is it not the responsibility of the domain entity's validator that holds the value objects? Or otherwise a domain service, if this logic does not belong to a specific domain entity?

Comment: @L-Four What you are suggesting fits my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value objects rarely exists on their own and are usually aggregated within an entity which is responsible for enforcing it's invariants.

> "I do not want to keep both values in one object because I do not need
>   them to be coupled when I use those values"

If there is a business rule that spans these values then they probably should be part of the same aggregate. The values themselves will not be directly coupled one to the other, but the aggregate would hold both.

Answer (score 0):

> Rule goes one price cannot be greater than other. There might be case when only one of them are specified.

If those two prices go really together and change together like `price-from / price-to` it is also possible to have `PriceRange` value object that can check those rules.

```
public class PriceRange
{
    public PriceRange(Price from, Price to)
    {
        // Check all rules here
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public Price From { get; }
    public Price To { get; }
}
```

Checking rules in the Aggregate Root can be better

- if AR state enforces price rules
- if those two prices change separately